# Entity Framework Inserting object inserts records in linked tables

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to seed some data into a Code First table, but I'm probably doing it wrong.

> I am getting duplicate rows in the Department table when I try to add
>   a Person.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

---

### **[Table Person]**

```
int Id;
string Name;
Department Dept;
```

### **[Table Department]**

```
int Id;
string DeparmentName;
```

In one method I seeded Department with several entries.

Then, in another method, I try to Add a Person, but because person has a Department object in it, IT adds a duplicate Deparment to the Department table.

The code below is not exactly what I have because I was trying to shorten it for this posting, but the idea is the same.

```
var dbContext = new Context();
// Get the Department for this user
var assignedDept = dbContext.Departments.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id== 40);


var seededUser = new Person 
{
Department = assignedDept,
Name = "John Doe"
};


var db = new Context();
db.Person.Add(seededUser);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a really easy fix here,

```
db.Person.AddOrUpdate(seededUser);
```

And give the row an actual id

eg

```
var seededUser = new Person 
{
    Id = 1,
    Department = assignedDept,
    Name = "John Doe"
};
```

heres a real life example

https://github.com/lukemcgregor/StaticVoid.Blog/blob/master/Blog/Data/Migrations/Configuration.cs

Comment: This is pretty close. It is not added a duplicate Department anymore, but the Person record has a NULL for the Department_Id.

It is updating the record, but not the Department.  Any ideas?

Comment: I found this answer here. Before calling the AddOrUpdate(seededUser) and dbContext.SaveChanges(), I had to call dbContext.Department.AddOrUpdate().

After that, it worked!

Thanks for your assistance.  The Code sample was really helpful.